# How can I hide the Resharper menu button in vs 2012

Tags: menu, resharper

I recently installed Resharper but a Resharper menu button was automatically added in the menu bar.
I don't want to disable the Resharper functionalities, I just want to hide or remove the menu button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't remove the Resharper menu as it is part of the installation. (And why would you want to as you wouldn't be able to access many of its features?)

Comment: Just hiding it  (not disabling it) so my boss wouldn't detect that i was able to install a program (my user rights isnt high enough to install, for some reason, I was able to install resharper without even bypassing any access rights)

Comment: Rather than hiding it from your boss, you should persuade them to let you use it and even get them to pay for it for you as it will make you more productive.